# Connecting 40+ transmitter coils to Raspberry Pi

Tags: gpio, pi-4, power-supply, wireless, matrix-creator

I am currently working on a school project to make the [wireless charging platform](https://shop.tesla.com/product/wireless-charging-platform)
from scratch but with more surface for originality. My current design requires 42 transmitter coils and these coils will be transferring power via induction/ resonant coupling. Furthermore, these coils will be sending analog ping to detect receiver coils and will be receiving analog pings from receiver coils.

I am currently thinking of using raspberry pi 4B as I got one for free from my college. However, I've never used it before and reading the data sheet made me a bit confused on which pins to use and how many pins I could use.

For now, my plan to connect the 42 transmitter coils by using a matrix? This seemed to be the popular method of cramming a large number of IOs on the PI or other micro-processors/controllers for digital IOs but I am not sure if they work for analog IOs.

Furthermore, typical resonant coupling happens at 100khz. Can the PI output such frequency? I believe the power requirements for the transmitter coils are within the ranges of the PI.

If anyone worked with a large number of analog inputs for Raspberry PI please share some tips!

Thanks.

Comment: Why 42? This is the Meaning of Life the Universe and Everything.

Comment: what's 6 times 9 :p